# Python Terminology: when we import x from package, is x a method?

Tags: python, python-import, terminology

For example: if we had `from collections import Counter` is `Counter` a "method"?

Comment: In this case, [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a class

Comment: in general, when you do `from <module> import foo`, `foo` could be anything (a submodule, a function, or a class). You cannot however dive down into the class and import a specific method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, collections contains classes, and Counter is one of them.  Inside Counter there will be methods.

There are a lot of examples of this, as in datetime.

For example, you are free to do this:

Scenario:  If all you need is the time:

```
import datetime
xtime = datetime.datetime.time()
```

but you can simplify your code a bit by doing this:

```
from datetime import datetime
xtime = datetime.time()
```

So the answer to your question is no.  Counter is not a method.